# kechkfault infected with signal 12 while launching Sybase 12.5.4

Tags: solaris, sybase

I am having troubles accessing my Sybase 12.5.4 instance on Solaris 9 because when I launch it, I get the following log:

```
00:00000:00001:2016/06/02 11:37:54.32 server  Database 'master' is now online.
00:00000:00000:2016/06/02 11:37:54.33 kernel  Current process (0x40004) infected with signal 12 (SIGSYS)
00:00000:00000:2016/06/02 11:37:54.33 kernel  Address 0xff3dc0dc (), siginfo (code, address) = (-1, 0x00001e27)
00:00000:00000:2016/06/02 11:37:54.33 kernel  kechkfault: engine 0: scheduler infected with signal 12 (SIGSYS)
00:00000:00000:2016/06/02 11:37:54.33 kernel  pc: 0x00910c98 pcstkwalk+0x24(0xfc746c80, 0xfc74663c, 0x0144c800, 0x00000002, 0x00000000)
00:00000:00000:2016/06/02 11:37:54.33 kernel  pc: 0x00910b74 ucstkgentrace+0x1ac(0x00040004, 0x00000002, 0x0000270f, 0x00000000, 0x00000000)
00:00000:00000:2016/06/02 11:37:54.33 kernel  pc: 0x0089cee4 ucbacktrace+0xac(0x00000000, 0x00000001, 0xfc746fa0, 0x00000001, 0x00000000)
00:00000:00000:2016/06/02 11:37:54.33 kernel  pc: 0x008b5bb4 keipanic+0x5c(0x0000c378, 0x00000000, 0x0000000c, 0x013b0a24, 0x00000000)
00:00000:00000:2016/06/02 11:37:54.33 kernel  pc: 0x008cee7c kisignal+0x1d8(0x01452000, 0xfc747838, 0xfc747580, 0x00000000, 0x00016928)
00:00000:00000:2016/06/02 11:37:54.33 kernel  pc: 0xff0256c8 __sighndlr+0xc(0x0000000c, 0xfc747838, 0xfc747580, 0x008ceca4, 0x00016928)
00:00000:00000:2016/06/02 11:37:54.33 kernel  pc: 0xff01f320 call_user_handler+0x234(0x0000000c, 0xfc747838, 0xfc747580, 0x00000030, 0x00000027)
00:00000:00000:2016/06/02 11:37:54.34 kernel  pc: 0xff01f4d0 sigacthandler+0x64(0x0000000c, 0xfc747838, 0xfc747580, 0x00000000, 0x00000000)
00:00000:00000:2016/06/02 11:37:54.34 kernel  pc: 0xff3d8ab8 (0xfc747980, 0x000000a3, 0x00000001, 0x0000000c, 0x0001555c)
00:00000:00000:2016/06/02 11:37:54.34 kernel  pc: 0xff3d33c0 (0xff05b848, 0xff05a5e4, 0x00000000, 0xff05a000, 0x00000000)
00:00000:00000:2016/06/02 11:37:54.34 kernel  pc: 0xff3dc03c (0xff05b848, 0xff05a5e4, 0x00000000, 0xff05a000, 0x00000000)
00:00000:00000:2016/06/02 11:37:54.34 kernel  pc: 0xff043e8c _aio_unlock+0x38(0x00000000, 0xffffffff, 0x00000001, 0x00000000, 0x00000000)
00:00000:00000:2016/06/02 11:37:54.34 kernel  pc: 0xff0424a8 aiowait+0x104(0x00f419fc, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000)
00:00000:00000:2016/06/02 11:37:54.34 kernel  pc: 0x008a6220 kaio__dpoll+0x64(0x01452000, 0xfc7476e0, 0x00000000, 0xfc746d10, 0x00000000)
00:00000:00000:2016/06/02 11:37:54.34 kernel  pc: 0x008a90c8 dcheck+0xe4(0x00deb400, 0x00000000, 0x01452000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000)
00:00000:00000:2016/06/02 11:37:54.34 kernel  pc: 0x00905630 kpcheckio+0x550(0x01452000, 0x00f42400, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000001)
00:00000:00000:2016/06/02 11:37:54.34 kernel  pc: 0x00903ca0 kpsched+0xaa0(0x00deb400, 0x01454800, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000)
00:00000:00000:2016/06/02 11:37:54.34 kernel  pc: 0x00926f74 _coldstart(0x00000000, 0x00903200, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000)
00:00000:00000:2016/06/02 11:37:54.34 kernel  end of stack trace, kernel service process: kpid 262148
00:00000:00000:2016/06/02 11:37:54.34 kernel  ueshutdown: exiting
00:00000:00000:2016/06/02 11:37:54.34 kernel  RTDS Server is already down.
00:00000:00000:2016/06/02 11:37:54.34 kernel  Abnormal exit detected - SQL Server process level execution bindings will be cleared on startup.
```

I guess then it is not completely launched cause I see it in the running processes but when I tried to connect to it with `isql` I get the following message:

```
CT-LIBRARY error:
        ct_connect(): network packet layer: internal net library error: Net-Lib protocol driver call to connect two endpoints failed
```

Any idea ? 
Thank you for your help.

Regards

Comment: Has anything changed recently on your server?  `SIGSYS` is usually for making an invalid system call, which seems unlikely if a system had been working in the past.

Comment: I am just installing the server. I installed Sybase ASE 12.5.4 successfully, then I resize the master.dat, and then I had an error which I can't remember when I tried to create a new database on the device. From then, I was unable to restart ASE properly. And now I tried to uninstall it, but I get `Setting server name in Adaptive Server...
Task failed` when trying to install it again..

Comment: What kind of device did you install the database on?  It looks like it doesn't support true `kaio` calls from the stack trace.

Comment: Device? Well that's a virtual machine in a datacenter. A Solaris 9

Comment: So it's never worked?

Comment: Indeed I was never able to create on database. I probably missed something during the installation process or maybe I have issues with my Solaris 9 OS. Will try to reinstall it and read between the lines of the pre-installation guide of ASE but reinstalling Sybase. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This indicates some kind of a bug in ASE. You should contact Techsupport, either to see which newer version you could use that has the bug fixed, or whether there are any configuration settings that could avoid this from occurring.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Using a developer licence I can't have the tech support. Since I am now stuck and can't even reinstall a clean version of ASE, I will reinstall Solaris, and try again, will read closely the pre-installation guide of ASE 12.5.4. Can it have something to do with `shm-memory` configuration or something. Since the only doubt I have in my installation process is about this. I am more used to set this with Solaris 10 in which it is easier with the `projmod -s -K` comment. Hope you see what I mean..